# Module 'Alamofire' has no member named 'upload'

Tags: swift, alamofire, ios13

I am trying to upload an image using swift to the server. i tried `NSMutableURLRequest` with `URLSession`. i received network connection lost. I thought it will be a better way to simply use `Alamofire` but got into a problem as `xcode` doesn't find the function `update`.

Any idea how to upload image with Alamofire? or find the update func?

the code for alamofire:

```
func uploadImageWithAlmofire(url: String) {
        let params: Parameters = ["name": "abcd", "gender": "Male"]
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:
            {
                (multipartFormData) in
                multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.yourimageView.image!, 0.1)!, withName: "file", fileName: "file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                for (key, value) in params
                {
                    multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
                }
        }, to:url,headers:nil)
        { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload,_,_ ):
                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    //Print progress
                })
                upload.responseJSON
                    { response in
                        //print response.result
                        if response.result.value != nil
                        {
                            let dict :NSDictionary = response.result.value! as! NSDictionary
                            let status = dict.value(forKey: "status")as! String
                            if status=="1"
                            {
                              print("DATA UPLOAD SUCCESSFULLY")
                            }
                        }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the code that you want to use?

Comment: added the code im using for alamofire

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you check [Uploading Data to a Server](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#uploading-data-to-a-server) example, it uses `AF` instead of `Alamofire`:

```swift
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    multipartFormData.append(Data("one".utf8), withName: "one")
    multipartFormData.append(Data("two".utf8), withName: "two")
}, to: "https://httpbin.org/post")
    .responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(Data(self.businessType.utf8), withName: "business_type")
        
        let theFileName1 = (self.doc1.absoluteString as NSString).lastPathComponent
        multipartFormData.append(self.doc1, withName: "key_value", fileName: theFileName1, mimeType: "image/png")
        
    }, to: "https://www.test_document.php") //POST URL
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
        }
```